# Swipable tabs using angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to build tabs which can be swiped by swipping on their content.
To be specific, when I swipe right on a tab's content(body) I want the previous tab's content to be displayed. This is similar to what is available in Whatsapp to navigate between the three tabs: calls, chats and contacts.

I want to implement this using angular material module. I know about md-swipe-left and md-swipe-right. But how do I change the body of the tabs??  Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the heart of the answer:

```
    $scope.onSwipeRight = function(tab_num){
        if( tab_num < 0){
            return;
        }
        $scope.selectedIndex = tab_num;   
    }

    $scope.onSwipeLeft = function(tab_num){
        if( tab_num > l){
        //l is number of tabs I have
            return;
        }
        $scope.selectedIndex = tab_num;        
    }
```

Then, use *md-swipe-left="onSwipeLeft(selectedIndex+1)"* and *md-swipe-right="onSwipeRight(selectedIndex-1)"* on the *md-tabs* directive.

That is all you need!!

Answer (score 0):

use **md-selected** attribute of **md-tabs**

HTML

```
<md-tabs class="md-accent" md-selected="selectedIndex" md-swipe-left="changeTab(1)" md-swipe-right="changeTab(0)">
```

Controller

```
$scope.selectedIndex = 0;
$scope.changeTab = function(tab_){
    $scope.selectedIndex = tab_;
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you are considering only two tabs, 0 and 1. Am I right?

Comment: yes. but if you have multiple tabs then use md-swipe in <md-tab-body> and increase and decrease parameter value of **changeTab** function

Comment: Thank you very much!! It was simple enough.